# All outputs by AI model is 0.0039+{some random number} for every image input in my android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am building an android app for my college project name "AI Pneumonia Detector" which takes input image from user gallary and predicts how likely is the person have pneumonia.

In my app I imported the model get bitmap of image from gallery
then resize it to (224, 224) which is input size for model
then convert it to a tensor image
then get bytebuffer from tensor image
then feed bytebuffer as input to model

But after all this model alway values starting with 0.0039 for every image (even on positive one where it should be > 0.5)(model works perfectly on python).

My app code is:

```
package com.shekhardwivedi.aipneumoniadetector;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Debug;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.shekhardwivedi.aipneumoniadetector.ml.AiModel;
import com.shekhardwivedi.aipneumoniadetector.ml.Stacked;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.ops.DequantizeOp;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.ops.QuantizeOp;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ImageProcessor;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.ResizeOp;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class predictionscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button upload;
    TextView prediction;
    ImageView imageView;
    boolean debuFlag = false;
    String debuGlobal = "";


    public static final int GET_FROM_GALLERY = 3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_predictionscreen);

        upload = findViewById(R.id.button);
        prediction = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        prediction.setText("Result: Unavailable\nUpload Image");

        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.tittle).into(imageView);



        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), GET_FROM_GALLERY);

                prediction.setText("Upload Image");

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //Detects request codes
        if(requestCode==GET_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                //Picasso.get().load(data).centerCrop().into(imageView);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                int height = bitmap.getHeight();

                int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
                ByteBuffer imageByteBuffer = preProcessImage(bitmap);

                prediction.setText("Processing");

                String pred1 = stackedModel(imageByteBuffer);
                //String pred2 = aiModel(bitmap);

                prediction.setText(String.format("%s", pred1));


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public ByteBuffer preProcessImage(Bitmap imgBitmap){
        int width = imgBitmap.getWidth();
        int height = imgBitmap.getHeight();
        int newHeight = 224;
        int newWidth = 224;
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        // Create a matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        // Resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // Recreate the new Bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

        // Initialization code
        // Create an ImageProcessor with all ops required. For more ops, please
        // refer to the ImageProcessor Architecture section in this README.
        ImageProcessor imageProcessor = new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                        .add(new ResizeOp(224, 224, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR)).add(new DequantizeOp(0, 1/255.0f)).build();
        // Create a TensorImage object. This creates the tensor of the corresponding
        // tensor type (uint8 in this case) that the TensorFlow Lite interpreter needs.
        TensorImage tensorImage = new TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32);
        // Preprocess the image
        tensorImage.load(resizedBitmap);
        tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(tensorImage);

        ByteBuffer imageBuffer = tensorImage.getBuffer();


        return imageBuffer;

    }


    public String stackedModel(ByteBuffer byteBuffer){
        String debu1 = Float.toString(byteBuffer.getFloat(100));
        String debu2 = Float.toString(byteBuffer.getFloat(200));
        String debu3 = Float.toString(byteBuffer.getFloat(300));
        String debu4 = Float.toString(byteBuffer.getFloat(400));

        String debu = "("+debu1+","+ debu2 +","+ debu3+","+ debu4+")";
        debuGlobal += debu;



        try {
            Stacked model = Stacked.newInstance(this);

            // Creates inputs for reference.
            TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 224, 224, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);
            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

            // Runs model inference and gets result.
            Stacked.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
            TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

            float [] out = outputFeature0.getFloatArray();
            int leng = out.length;
            String pred = String.format("Probability: %s", Double.toString(out[0] / 255.0));


            // Releases model resources if no longer used.
            model.close();
            return pred+"::"+debuGlobal;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Handle the exception
        }
        return "errored";

    }

    public String aiModel(Bitmap imgBitmap){

        int width = imgBitmap.getWidth();
        int height = imgBitmap.getHeight();
        int newHeight = 150;
        int newWidth = 150;
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        // Create a matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        // Resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // Recreate the new Bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

        // Initialization code
        // Create an ImageProcessor with all ops required. For more ops, please
        // refer to the ImageProcessor Architecture section in this README.
        ImageProcessor imageProcessor = new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                .add(new ResizeOp(150, 150, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
                .build();
        // Create a TensorImage object. This creates the tensor of the corresponding
        // tensor type (uint8 in this case) that the TensorFlow Lite interpreter needs.
        TensorImage tensorImage = new TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32);
        // Preprocess the image
        tensorImage.load(resizedBitmap);
        tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(tensorImage);

        ByteBuffer imageBuffer = tensorImage.getBuffer();

//        String debu1 = Float.toString(imageBuffer.getFloat(100));
//        String debu2 = Float.toString(imageBuffer.getFloat(200));
//        String debu3 = Float.toString(imageBuffer.getFloat(300));
//        String debu4 = Float.toString(imageBuffer.getFloat(400));
//
//        String debu = debu1 + debu2 + debu3 + debu4;


        try {
            AiModel model = AiModel.newInstance(this);

            // Creates inputs for reference.
            TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 150, 150, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);
            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(imageBuffer);

            // Runs model inference and gets result.
            AiModel.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
            TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

            float [] out = outputFeature0.getFloatArray();
            int leng = out.length;
            String pred = String.format("Probability: %s", Double.toString(out[0] / 255.0));

            // Releases model resources if no longer used.
            model.close();

            return pred;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Handle the exception
        }
        return "none returned";
    }


}
```

Comment: I think no one can help you here without actually getting information about your model which you trained, what kind of model, how you trained etc

Comment: model is trained with this code: https://www.kaggle.com/preatcher/pneumonia-detection-stacked-model-94

Answer (score 1):

Before blaming the model, we need to consider what can go wrong in preprocessing data(image in your case).

So i would suggest you to check and test following:

- Check image processing, make sure that **imageByteBuffer** is correctly initialized and it's content is different when you select different pictures. Just add some logging and see if it's true.
- Make sure that you correctly initialized TensorFlow model in app.
- Check that you are retrieving result from right item in the output array.

Comment: absolutely agree, I was checking Kaggle and was about to question the same

Comment: Here is what I found: the imageByteBuffer is different for different images so I think input to model is correct. But I also found out that imageBytebuffer has values like 12.0, 225.0 , always ending with .0 , so I take a look into python testing code where they divide each pixel by 255 (i.e img = img/255) and the values were like 0.23, 0.001 etc. So after some digging, I used DeQuantize op function, now It gives different predicted value every time but values always start with 0.0039 then some random numbers(even on the positive case images where it should be more than 0.5).

Comment: I have updated the code please check, and suggest something, Thank you.

Comment: @YauheniBaradaukin Help please.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my tensorimage was not quantized and I was trying to divide the answer by / 255. After fixing it the model is working fine.

from this incomplete code:

```
ImageProcessor imageProcessor = new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                .add(new ResizeOp(150, 150, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
                .build();
```

to completed code:

```
ImageProcessor imageProcessor = new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                        .add(new ResizeOp(224, 224, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR)).add(new DequantizeOp(0, 1/255.0f)).build();
```

and from this:

```
String pred = String.format("Probability: %s", Double.toString(out[0]/ 255.0f));
```

to this:

```
String pred = String.format("Probability: %s", Double.toString(out[0]));
```